# Add n amount of columns in PyQt5 at a scroll area widget

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5

I need to create n amount of widgets inside a scroll area or similar, and this widgets should contain a label and a delete button or similar. I have not achieved how to get n amounts of labels, they are not shown.

This should add the widget:

```py
name = QtWidgets.QLabel()
name.setText(str(ui.nombre.toPlainText))
ui.elementos.addWidget(name, 0, 0, 1, 1)
```

And this is where "elementos" is defined:

```py
self.scroll = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self.gridLayoutWidget_2)
self.elementos = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
self.elementos.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 500, 400))
self.Punto.addWidget(self.scroll, 4, 0, 1, 3)
```

And the Punto is defined here:

```py
self.gridLayoutWidget_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.widget_central)
self.gridLayoutWidget_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1004, 105, 300, 400))
self.Punto = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget_2)
```

Full code: https://github.com/Jaime02/Proyecto-de-investigacion-2019-Dibujo-tecnico/blob/experimental/error

Comment: Are you using `ui.elementos.addWidget(name, 0, 0, 1, 1)` for all the labels you are creating? If so you are placing them all at the same position in you grid layout.

Comment: @Heike I know, but I can not see any widget, there should be at least one

Comment: Are you setting `ui.elementos` as the layout of your main widget? Or better yet, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Heike No, it is contained in the "Punto" grid layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a grid layout and adding widgets to it but you are not using the grid layout as a layout for any of your widgets. To show the grid layout in the scroll area, you need to create a separate widget, set the layout of this widget to the grid layout and display the widget in the scroll area, e.g. in `UiVentana.__init__` you need to replace

```
self.scroll = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self.gridLayoutWidget_2)
self.elementos = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
self.elementos.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 500, 400))
```

with

```
self.scroll = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self.gridLayoutWidget_2)

# create widget to display in scroll area
self.scroll_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
self.scroll_widget.resize(500, 400)

# create grid layout and use it as the layout of self.scroll_widget
self.elementos = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
self.scroll_widget.setLayout(self.elementos)

# display self.scroll_widget in the scroll area
self.scroll.setWidget(self.scroll_widget)
```

In addition, in `Renderizador.crear_punto` you need to use `name.setText(str(ui.nombre.toPlainText()))` (with parentheses) instead of `name.setText(str(ui.nombre.toPlainText))`.

Comment: I have done it but now the scroll bar appears at the top of the grid and is really small

Comment: I have partialy fixed it adding self.Punto.addWidget(self.scroll, 4, 0, 1, 1)

Comment: It looks like you replaced one line too many. You should keep the line `self.Punto.addWidget(self.scroll, 4, 0, 1, 3)` from the original code.